# Change of variable in integral, from real to complex variable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, change-of-variable

I have an integral depending on the following expression
$$-(k_{20}-k_{10})^2 + (k_{2x}-k_{1x})^2 + (K_{2z}-K_1)^2 - K_2^2$$
where the integration variables are $k_{20}$ and $K_{2z}$.
I need transformation (possibly a "rotation", even if it is, strickly speaking, a boost) such that this expression becomes
$$(k_{20}'-\sqrt{k_{10}^2-K_1^2})^2 + (k_{2x}-k_{1x})^2 + K_{2z}'^2 - K_2^2.$$
Now if $k_{10}^2-K_1^2>0$ the transformation is easy to find and it is
$$k_{20}' = \frac{\sqrt{k_{10}^2-K_1^2}}{k_{10}^2-K_1^2}k_{10}k_{20} - \frac{\sqrt{k_{10}^2-K_1^2}}{k_{10}^2-K_1^2}K_1K_{2z}$$
$$K_{2z}' = -\frac{\sqrt{k_{10}^2-K_1^2}}{k_{10}^2-K_1^2}K_1k_{20} + \frac{\sqrt{k_{10}^2-K_1^2}}{k_{10}^2-K_1^2}k_{10}K_{2z}.$$
The problems occur when $k_{10}^2-K_1^2<0$. I can only reconduce the expression to 
$$(k_{20}'-i\sqrt{k_{10}^2-K_1^2})^2 + (k_{2x}-k_{1x})^2 + K_{2z}'^2 - K_2^2$$
and one of the factors of the change of variable is imaginary. My questions are:

1. Is it possible to find a transformation for $k_{10}^2-K_1^2<0$ to obtain $(k_{20}'-\sqrt{k_{10}^2-K_1^2})^2 + (k_{2x}-k_{1x})^2 + K_{2z}'^2 - K_2^2$ without using complex factors?
2. If it is not possible, when is it legitimate to change the integration variable from real to complex? I can't find anything online or in my textbooks.